# A Visual Comparison of Emphasized Text and Italicized Text---What is the Difference?

Tags: typography, italic, emphasis

Please consider the output of the following code in book class:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Huge

\noindent \emph{Emphasized Text} \\[10pt]
\textit{Italicized Text}
\\[25pt]
What is the difference?
\end{document}
```

[image]

To me, there appears to be no difference in the typography of the displayed text when, in the first case `\emph` is used, versus the second case, `\textit` was used.

QUESTION: Is my observation correct here; if so, then why would any one of the two commands be preferred over the other? But if there is a difference in the two commands, perhaps someone would point out what it is.

Thank you.

Comment: Also `\emph` can be nested, so in `\emph{This or \emph{that} word}` "that" would actually switch back to roman (upright) type.

Comment: This is  effectively a duplicate of the question @campa linked, but the answers here are better in that they discuss `\DeclareEmphSequence`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*By default*, the difference in output between `\textit{some text}` and `\emph{some text}` is none.  `\emph` by default does `\textit` internally.

The difference between them is about their meaning:  `\textit` means literally "text in italic font" while `\emph` means "emphasize this text".  Again, by default in LaTeX, emphasis is done with italics, but you can change that by doing:

```
\DeclareEmphSequence{\bfseries}
```

to get `\emph` to make bold text.

Another difference is that `\textit{some \textit{italic} text}` typsets "*some italic text*", all in italics.  `\emph{some \emph{emphasized} text}` typesets "*some* emphasized *text*", with "emphasized" in upright font (by default, `\emph` alternates between italics and upright font).

You can change the default set of font change commands for emphasis using `\DeclareEmphSequence`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\DeclareEmphSequence{\itshape,\scshape,\itshape\bfseries,\normalfont}
\emph{one \emph{two \emph{three \emph{four}}}}

\DeclareEmphSequence{\tiny,\scriptsize,\footnotesize,\small,\normalsize,\large,\Large,\LARGE,\Huge}
\emph{one \emph{two \emph{three \emph{four \emph{five \emph{six \emph{seven \emph{eight \emph{nine \emph{ten \emph{eleven}}}}}}}}}}}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for this very informative answer.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is when you nest them. Also the font for \emph can be adjusted:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}


\emph{blub \emph{inner}}

\DeclareEmphSequence{\bfseries,\itshape}

\emph{blub \emph{inner}}

\end{document}
```

[image]